# Nested 'for' loops in native Google Sheets (no scripts)

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-for-loop

I'm aware that it's possible to emulate a for loop in Google Sheets via the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN({range_0 to iterate over}),{function_0 for each element in range_0}))
```

I've not been able to expand on the above approach to achieve the effect of a multi nested for loop. Is this possible? Ideally this would look something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN({range_0 to iterate over}),IF(LEN({range_0.1 to iterate over for each parent element in range_0}),{function_0.1 for each element in range_0.1},{OPTIONAL: function_0 for each element in range_0})))
```

**Example application:**
Iterating over each cell in a row for each row in a column (see below; I'm sure there are ways to achieve this effect via other methods, but I have use for the requested and specified method for cases where a single dynamic formula is necessary to keep up with an unknown and changing number of rows, columns, and functions involved):

**Raw data:**

| Thing | Type | Feature | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit | Seeds | $1 |
| Car | Automobile | Wheels | $6,000 |
| Laptop | Computer | Keyboard | $500 |
| Grape | Fruit | Tastiness | $0.50 |

**Theoretical formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(`Thing`),IF(LEN(COLUMNS({current row of `Thing`})),{current cell in current row of `Thing`} & " of column " & COLUMN({*current cell*}) & " and row " & ROW(`Thing`),""),""))
```

**Output of above theoretical formula:**

| Thing | Type | Feature | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple of column 1 and row 3 | Fruit of column 2 and row 3 | Seeds of column 3 and row 3 | $1 of column 4 and row 3 |
| Car of column 1 and row 4 | Automobile of column 2 and row 4 | Wheels of column 3 and row 4 | $6,000 of column 4 and row 4 |
| Laptop of column 1 and row 5 | Computer of column 2 and row 5 | Keyboard of column 3 and row 5 | $500 of column 4 and row 5 |
| Grape of column 1 and row 6 | Fruit of column 2 and row 6 | Tastiness of column 3 and row 6 | $0.50 of column 4 and row 6 |

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:E7), A3:E7&" of column "&COLUMN(A3:E7)&" and row "&ROW(A3:E7), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I wouldn't have thought to use the full array as the LEN() input. Thanks!